# Highlight search query function that works with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, search, full-text-search

I am  trying to create a function that takes a query and a result, and returns JSX with the result, but the query is highlighted in bold text. It should ignore special characters and capitalisation.

For example, if you search for `Stack` it should return '**Stäçk**overflow'. It should also ignore special characters such as spaces, dashes, &, @, %, etc.

So `Stack` as a query should return '**St-ack**overflow' or '**St ack**'overflow.

This is what I have come up so far, it works as long as there are no special characters. But I am having trouble to figure out how to do this with special characters included.

```
function highlightSearchQuery(searchQuery: string, result: string): JSX.Element {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${searchQuery})`, 'gi');
    const parts = result.split(regex);
    return (
        <>
            {parts.map((part, index) => {
                const isQueryMatch = part.toLowerCase() === searchQuery.toLowerCase();
                return <Fragment key={index}>{isQueryMatch ? <strong>{part}</strong> : part}</Fragment>;
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

Please note that I know how you can remove the special characters and compare, e.g. `const isQueryMatch =  part.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-zA-z0-9]+)/g, '') === searchQuery.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-zA-z0-9]+)/g, '');`.

But how do you remove the special characters **before the split**? And then put them back in the return **just as the original?**